# Ban user if they mention over 5 people

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Heyo Axmyo here,

I want to autoban user if they mention over 5 humans, not bots

but the code I tried to use doesn't do anything..

Any help would be appreciated!

```
client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.mentions.members.size > 5) {
    message.author.ban();
  } 
})
```

Comment: You should look for the error log of your code, wherever it runs. I'm pretty sure you have an `Uncaught TypeError: message.author.ban is not a function` waiting for you there which would have nudged you into the right direction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're in the right direction, your if statement is correct.

[`message.author` returns a `User`.](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=author)

[but `.ban()` is available only on `GuildMember`.](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=ban)

So you need to convert the `User` to a `GuildMember`. Luckily the message object contains the `Guild` that it was sent in, so you can do the following:

```js
client.on("message", message => {
  if(message.mentions.members.size > 5) {
    const user = message.author;
    const guildMember = message.guild.member(user);
    guildMember.ban();
  } 
})
```

Notice that `.ban()` returns a promise, so it might be a good idea to do the following, if you want to do additional things after the ban:

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
  if(message.mentions.members.size > 5) {
    const user = message.author;
    const guildMember = message.guild.member(user);
    await guildMember.ban();

    // Do other things...
  } 
})
```

### Edit

message object has a member property on it, thanks [Itamar S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68235835/ban-user-if-they-mention-over-5-people#comment120597853_68236059)

```js
client.on("message", async message => {
  if(message.mentions.members.size <= 5) return;

  await message.member.ban();
  // Do other things... 
})
```

Comment: Thank you, completely missed that. I've edited the answer.